# Sort list by date closest to now but not old dates

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list with dates that I would like to sort according to:

- Dates that is today should be sorted in the top
- Dates that is in the future should be sorted by closest date today (example today = 8th and we have the dates 18, 9, 11 should be sorted => 9, 11, 18)
- Dates older then today's date should be listed in the bottom of the list descending.

*What is the best way to do this*?:

- Is it to create a future list,
- old list and present list and then concat and sort them?
- Or can i achieve this in a better way?

To to make this even clearer **this is how the sorted list should look** like:

today => tomorrow => day after tomorrow => days in future.... => yesterday => older then yesterday

[image]

Comment: Isn't it just a descending sort? Am I missing something?

Comment: @CodingYoshi if i sort on descending, dates that is in the future would be sorted before todays date.

Comment: Please show what you have tried in order to solve this need

Comment: @GiladGreen just this itemList = itemList.OrderBy(x => x.EventStartDate).ToList();
                        return Json(itemList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  dont know where to start

Comment: This kind of sorting when it is a `List<T>` is a bit complex.The code woukldn't be huge but the logics may need a lot of thinking

Comment: @zackraiyan yeah that's the problem haha

Comment: @Patte , i guess i can post an answer if you post how your `List` looks and what is your expected result :)

Comment: @zackraiyan it's a regular date time in string format nothing special. If you need further explanation on the sorting (I know my question is hard to understand) i can write a pm to you if you need further instructions

Comment: how can u write a pm on SO ? just edit your qs bro :) that's all we need :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>()
{
    DateTime.Today,
    DateTime.Today.AddDays(1),
    DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2),
    DateTime.Today.AddDays(5),
    DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5)
};
```

> Dates that is today should be sorted in the top

```
DateTime today = dates.Where(x => x == DateTime.Today).First();
```

> Dates that is in the future should be sorted by closest date today (example today = 8th and we have the dates 18, 9, 11 should be sorted => 9, 11, 18)

```
List<DateTime> futureDates = dates.Where(x => x > today).ToList();
futureDates.Sort();
```

> Dates older then today's date should be listed in the bottom of the list descending.

```
List<DateTime> oldDates = dates.Where(x => x < today).OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```

And this is the final aggregated result:

```
var final = new List<DateTime>();
final.Add(today);
final.AddRange(futureDates);
final.AddRange(oldDates);
```

[<== Fiddle ==>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CqT7dX)